# Python Django Framework Error: Could Not Find 'My Tasks' in the h1 tag

Tags: python, html, django, coding-style, software-design

I am new to coding in Django. I am creating a Django App called Tasks.
My code within each of the following files will be included. I keep getting the error that 'Could not find 'My Tasks' in h1 tag'...Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhpN1.png)

**Error Message**

Ran
7 tests in 2.728s
FAILED (failures=5)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'
(venv) wyattsanchez@Wyatts-MacBook-Pro project-alpha-apr % python manage.py test tests, test_feature_16

Found 7 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'.
System check identified no issues (0 silenced)
FFFFF.
FAIL: test_has_ha_tag_for_no_tasks (tests, test_feature_16. FeatureTests)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"/Users/wyattsanchez/projects/project-alpha-apr/tests/test_feature_16.py", line 97, in test_has _hi_tag_for_no_tasks self.assertin‹ AssertionError:
'My Tasks' not found in 'Create a new task'
Could not find 'My Tasks' in the hi tag

FAIL: test_has_ha_tag_for_tasks (tests. test_feature_16 .FeatureTests)
| Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"/Users/wyattsanchez/projects/project-alpha-apr/tests/test_feature_16.py", line 109, in test_has_h1_tag_for_tasks self.asserting
AssertionError:
'My Tasks' not found in 'Create a new task': Could not find 'My Tasks' in the hi tag

FAIL: test_my_tasks _with _no_tasks_shows _message (tests, test_feature_16 .FeatureTests)
| Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/wyattsanchez/projects/project-alpha-apr/tests/test_feature_16.py", line 60, in test_my_tasks_with_no_tasks_shows_message self.assertin(
assertioncrrors
'You have no tasks' not found in 'HomeCreate a new taskCreate' : Did not find the message 'You have no tasks'
PASS SASSSASSSASSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSESSSESSSSSSSESSSSSSASSSASSSESSSESSE

FAIL: test_my_tasks_with_one_task_has_four_td_tags (tests.test_feature_16.FeatureTests)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"Users/wyattsanchez/projects/project-alpha-apr/tests/test_feature_16.py", line 85, in test_my_tasks_with_one_task_has_four_td_tags self.assertEquali
AssertionError:
4 : Should only have td tags for data rows

FAIL: test_my_tasks_with_one_task_to_see_task_name (tests. test_feature_16 .FeatureTests)
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000--..............
Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"/Users/wyattsanchez/projects/project-alpha-apr/tests/test_feature_16.py", line 68, in test_my_tasks_with_one_task_to_see_task_name self.assertIn(
AssertionError:
'yyyyYY' not found in 'HomeCreate a new taskCreate'
Did not find the name of the task assigned to
the user

Ran 7 tests in 2.8085
FAILED (failures=5)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'.
I (ovenw) wyattsanchez@Wyatts-MacBook-Pro project-alpha-apr %

**admin .py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from tasks.models import Task
# Register your models here.




@admin.register(Task)
class Task(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = (
       "name",
       "start_date",
       "due_date",
       "is_completed",
       "project",
       "assignee",
   )
```

**Apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class TasksConfig(AppConfig):
   default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
   name = "tasks"
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from tasks.models import Task




class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Task
       fields = [
           "name",
           "start_date",
           "due_date",
           "project",
           "assignee",
       ]
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from projects.models import Project




class Task(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="New Task")
   start_date = models.DateTimeField()
   due_date = models.DateTimeField()
   is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   project = models.ForeignKey(
       Project,
       related_name="tasks",
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   )
   assignee = models.ForeignKey(
       settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
       related_name="tasks",
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
       null=True,
   )
```

**Urls.py**

```
from tasks.views import create_task, show_my_tasks
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
   path("create/", create_task, name="create_task"),
   path("mine/", show_my_tasks, name="show_my_tasks"),
]
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from tasks.forms import TaskForm
from projects.views import list_projects
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from tasks.models import Task


@login_required
def create_task(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
       form = TaskForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           task = form.save()
           task.owner = request.user
           task.save()
           return redirect(list_projects)
   else:
       form = TaskForm()
   context = {
       "post_form": form,
       }
   return render(request, "tasks/create.html", context)



@login_required
def show_my_tasks(request):
   if request.user.is_anonymous:
       return redirect("login")
   showmytasks = Task.objects.filter(assignee=request.user.id)
   context = {
       "my_tasks": showmytasks}
   return render(request, "tasks/show_my_tasks.html", context)
```

**List.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>{{ project_object.title }}</title>
   </head>
   <header>
       <nav>
           <a href="{% url 'list_projects' %}">Home</a>
       </nav>
   </header>
   <body>
       <main>
           <div>
               <h1>My Tasks</h1>
               {% if my_tasks %}
                   <table>
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                               <th>Name</th>
                               <th>Start date</th>
                               <th>Due date</th>
                               <th>Is completed</th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                           {% for task in my_tasks %}
                               <tr>
                                   <td>{{ task.name }}</td>
                                   <td>{{ task.start_date }}</td>
                                   <td>{{ task.due_date }}</td>
                                   <td>{{ task.is_complete|yesno }}</td>
                               </tr>
                           {% endfor %}
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
               {% else %}
                   <p>You have no tasks</p>
               {% endif %}
           </div>
       </main>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Show_my_tasks.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>{{ project_object.title }}</title>
   </head>
   <header>
       <nav>
           <a href="{% url 'list_projects' %}">Home</a>
       </nav>
   </header>
   <body>
       <main>
           <div>
               <h1>Create a new task</h1>
               <form method="post">
                   {% csrf_token %}
                   {{ post_form.as_p }}
                   <button>Create</button>
               </form>
           </div>
       </main>
   </body>
</html>
```

I've tried following the error message and making tweaks to my code but I am lost now.

Comment: Hello Victor, Can you add your error log please ?
Futhermore, the HTML for "Show_my_tasks.html" seems to be the code to create a task. And "List.html", the code for "Show_my_tasks.html"

Comment: Hi Victor :)

you used `Task.objects.filter(assignee=request.user.id)` to get the tasks, but `assignee` is a foreign key to the user - so it must be `Task.objects.filter(assignee=request.user)` or `Task.objects.filter(assignee_id=request.user.id)`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Philippe I have included an image of the error message plus a text of the error message. Thanks you!

Comment: Victor, According to the error log, the issue regarding 'My Tasks' not found is because you have a Test checking if a h1 tag with text 'My Tasks' exists in the the file "Create a new task'. You should change the tests line 97 and 107 in order to resolve the issue. You also have other failed test, though without the test file, it's difficult to help you there.